# Passing array to function with dynamic declaration of array in C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, turbo-c++

I want to pass array to function in C/C++ without declaring and assigning it previously.
As in C# we can:

```
fun(new int[] {1, 1}); //this is a function call for void fun(int[]) type function
```

I am not very sure about the correctness of the above code. But I had done something like this in C#.

How can we pass array to function using dynamic declaration (on the spot declaration)??

I'd tried it using following way. But no luck

```
fun(int {1,1});
fun(int[] {1,1});
fun((int[]) {1,1});
```

can't we do so..??

Comment: Why the turbo-c and turbo-c++ tags? Do you use those compilers?

Comment: yes @RedX. I am using Turbo C++

Comment: Do you want a C or a C++ solution? This makes a significant difference here.

Comment: It should work in Turbo C++ compiler @BjörnPollex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C99 and later, this:

```
foo((int[]){2,4,6,8});
```

is approximately the same as this:

```
int x[] = {2,4,6,8};
foo(x);
```

Prior to C99, this is not possible.  C++ does not support this syntax either.

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi: C99 is the second most recent version of the C language, which Turbo-C probably doesn't support.

Comment: and what about Borland C/C++ compiler..??

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi: That's a very ancient compiler as well.  I suggest moving to a modern development environment.

Comment: Actually I was solving some previous year Question Paper for my practical exam of C++. They provide Turbo and Borland compilers only. That's why i was finding a solution for that. But now I'd know, I have to declare it before passing.

Comment: You can download several C++ IDEs for free. I recommend [CodeLite](http://www.codelite.org/).

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, you can use an initializer list:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

void fun(std::initializer_list<int> numbers)
{
    for (int x : numbers)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    fun( {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19} );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in ANSI C99 and C11, but not in C89.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest using a variable argument list?

The declaration syntax would be as follows:

```
void Function(int Count, ...) {
     va_list va;
     va_start(va, Count);
     for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i) {
         int nextVar = va_arg(va, int);
         //Do some stuff with the array element
     }
     va_end(va);
}
```

This function is called with:

```
Function(4, 2, 3, 1, 5);
```

2, 3, 1 and 5 are the 'array elements'.

Alternatively, if you 'need' an array to go through within that function, it's easy to move the variable list to a proper (dynamic) array, by using new and delete.

Within the va-function:

```
 int *Array = new int[Count];
 for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i) {
      Array[i] = va_arg(va, int);
 }
 //Do Stuff with Array
 delete[] Array;
```

Comment: It should work. It's standard C, as far as I know and is the only way that comes to mind, to pass an 'array' without initializing one first.

Why don't you just give it a go and see if it works as you expect it to?

Comment: @alinsoar Actually it's not a different problem...the problem is, that he wants to pass a variable number of elements of the same type, without having to initialize an array of that type prior to the function.
As such, the variable argument list is a valid solution for the problem.

Comment: Yes. The problem is * pass a parameter without having declared it *. The problem is clear.