# array in parameter without variable Initialization

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variables, parameters

is it possible to do this?

```
void putAverage(float *avg, int *arrData, int size) {
    int i,sum = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < size;i++) {
        sum += *(arrData + i);
    }
    *avg = sum / size;
}

int main() {
    float i;
    putAverage(&i, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 5);
    printf("%f\n",i);
}
```

because if i run it, it shows error like this

```
error: expected expression before '{' token
error: too few arguments to function 'putAverage'
note: declared here
```

if it possible please make a correction, if not please give me the best way to do it.

Comment: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` --> `(int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, `*avg = sum / size;` --> `*avg = (float)sum / size;`

Comment: It's simpler to use `arrData[i]` than `*(arrData + i)` – and there's no performance difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void putAverage(float *avg, const int *arrData, int size) {
    int i,sum = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < size;i++) {
        sum += *(arrData + i);
    }
    *avg = (float)sum / size;
}

int main() {
    float i;
    putAverage(&i, (const int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 5);
    printf("%f\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591338/passing-array-to-function-with-dynamic-declaration-of-array-in-c-c) for more understanding.

`(const int[]){ 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 }` is same as

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 };
  foo(arr); //Passing the array
```

`const` is added to make sure we don't modify the array by mistake.

`(float)sum` is for typecasting the integer division and store as float

Comment: Good code but you should also explain what changes you made and why